# How to make two columns start at the same height using tabular and minipage?

Tags: tables, minipage

I have a table (*tabular*) with two columns and a *minipage* in each.  The left column appears at a lower height than the right column.  How can I make the column contents at the same height level?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[b6paper, 10pt, twoside, openright, final]{memoir}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.25cm}{.5cm}{*}                                                                                                                                                                                                        
\setulmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{*}{1}                                                                                                                                                                                                            
\checkandfixthelayout{}                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
\usepackage[x-1a]{pdfx}                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
\hypersetup{final}                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
\usepackage[base]{babel}                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
\usepackage{libertine}                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
\usepackage{gregoriotex}                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
\usepackage{lipsum}                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
\begin{document}                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  \begin{tabular}{p{.45\textwidth} | p{.45\textwidth}}                                                                                                                                                                                        
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      \section{Se\~nal}                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      \lipsum[2]                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    \end{minipage}                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      \section*{SIGNUM}                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      \lipsum[3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    \end{minipage}                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  \end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
\end{document}
```

Comment: A [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) usually means that most of the `\usepackage{}`'s you do not need are removed i.e. I do not see how `\usepackage{lettrine}` is relevant to your question. Could you please follow that link and remove everything that is not relevant to your question please? I upvoted as you're new and included code (which is a bonus) but could you strip away unnecessary lines please

Comment: remove the minipages and the c column so you have a 2-column table. `p` colums top align by default so that is all you need

Comment: You could use paracol instead of tabular, assuming 2 columns instead of three..  You would need `\globalcounter{section}`.

Comment: @JamesT, thanks for the clarification.  I'll edit the code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks I eliminated the c and now I have two columns.  Great!

Comment: @JohnKormylo, thanks.  I'll give it a try!